Normalised degree centrality in subway network of Hong Kong
I made a network of the subway in Hong Kong using Open Street Map. Then, I wanted to visualise normalised degree centrality in the network. This is my code:
G_undirected = nx.Graph(metro_HK)
deg_HK_norm =nx.degree_centrality(G_undirected)


nx.set_node_attributes(G_undirected,dict(deg_HK_norm),'degree_norm')

deg_color_norm=[(node['degree_norm']) for i, node in G_undirected.nodes(data=True)]
deg_size_norm=[(node['degree_norm']*1000) for i, node in G_undirected.nodes(data=True)]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,12))
**pos=nx.spring_layout(G_undirected)**
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G_undirected, pos,edge_color='black', 
    width=0.4)
nod=nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G_undirected,
    pos = pos,
    node_color= deg_color_norm,
    node_size= deg_size_norm)

 plt.colorbar(nod,label="Degree Centrality",orientation="horizontal", shrink=0.5)
 plt.axis("off")
 plt.title("Network of HK metro with normalised degree centrality",fontsize=15)
 plt.show()

The network is appearing wrong because of the spring layout. What position can I do for the network to appear in the same layout as the real subway system?
I was expecting a network with nodes of different size and colour. That happend. However the layout is not the same as my original metro_HK.
